# js output in php code

Tags: javascript, php, forms

From the dynamic html form, I get the following inputs in js manner in php code :

```
$sl   = $_POST['sl'];   // input: 12
$name = $_POST['name']; // input: Jhon
$code = $_POST['code']; // input: 456
$val  = $_POST['val'];  // input: 10023

for ($i = 0; $i < count($sl); $i++) {
    $email_body .= "SL_No: " . $sl[$i] . "\n". "Name: " . $name[$i] . "code: " . $code[$i] . " Value: " . $val[$i] . "\n\n";
}
```

**The out put is:**

```
SL_No: 12
Name: Jhon Code:456 Value: 10023
```

**Whereas I need in the output following manner:**

```
SL[12]; 
Name[Jhon][456]="10023";
```

Can anybody help ne in correcting the PHP code

Comment: You are not clear, you need array or string ?

Comment: string only (i.e sending the out put in Email )

Comment: Any reason why you are not using json?

Comment: I am not having any idea aout JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = "SL[". $sl[$i] ."]";
$body .= "Name[".$name[$i]."][".$code[$i]."]=". $val[$i];
```

Comment: In the second line "val"; to be apear

Comment: If you are using the double quotes, there is no necessity for concatenating them with `.` - you can just go with `"Name[$name[$i]][$code[$i]]=$val[$i]"`; and it will parsed acordingly

Comment: yeah we can do that too. I kept with the use intent.

Comment: Please have some text following your answer to make it more understandable to the community thanks.

Comment: **SL[12]; Name[Jhon][456]="10023";**    in the manner I need the output

Comment: Everything is there, try something yourself.